# Firing on both side Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a 2D platformer but my player is not firing on both side I don't know what is wrong with my script.

```css
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour 
{
 public float bulletSpeed;
 public GameObject bullet;
 public Transform bulletX;
 GameObject clone;


 void Update () 
 {
  if (Input.GetKeyUp ("space")) 
  {
   clone = Instantiate(bullet,new Vector3(bulletX.position.x,bulletX.position.y+0.1f,0f),Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

   if (GameObject.Find ("Player").GetComponent<Player> ().left == true)
    bulletSpeed = -30f;
   else
    bulletSpeed = 30f;

  }

  bullet.rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(bulletSpeed * 0.5f, 0f);
  Destroy (clone, 1f);

 }
}
```

I tried to increase velocity inside the if condition but bullet was moving faster than I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question was very hard to understand what you want to accomplish, but I can see some errors in your code that will render the "clone" you are creating, useless.

The update loop is continuously executing, and you have placed the destroy outside your "Press space" code block. Unity tries to destroy it every frame. Place it inside the space.

I feel it should look more like this:

```
    if (Input.GetKeyUp ("space")) 
    {
        clone = Instantiate(bullet,new Vector3(bulletX.position.x,bulletX.position.y+0.1f,0f),Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

        if (GameObject.Find ("Player").GetComponent<Player> ().left == true)
            bulletSpeed = -30f;
        else
            bulletSpeed = 30f;
            bullet.rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(bulletSpeed * 0.5f, 0f);
            Destroy (clone, 1f);
    }
```

This might not answer your question, but could you specify more what behaviour you are after? And what object is this script running on? (It is called `Bullet` with a field referance to another `bullet` ?)

Answer (score 0):

Debug.Log your bulletSpeed * 0.5f

If I am correct. Even if your Player is Looking at the other way. It is returning
an ABS number meaning (bulletSpeed = -30f & 0.f is != -44954 something but == 44954).

Alternatively you can use AddForce instead of Velocity. It is easier to control.

QUESTION. Why not use Instantiate Vector2?